# DNS is not saving

Tags: dns, google-dns

I'm using `D-Link DWM-152` Dongle to connect to the internet. I have changed `DNS` in my network connection to `Google DNS` and connect to the internet using software which has came with my dongle. Then i have checked my network connection's TCP/IP properties. Google DNS has removed and `Obtain DNS server address automatically` is selected.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Probably you are using DHCP, just edit the connection via Windows' own settings once you are online and change back to your customs DNS. NOTE that doing that may broke your current connection if DNS traffic is filtered. Try testing beforehand by using `nslookup`, then changing servers to google's : `server 8.8.8.8` and last test a DNS request `www.google.com`